# The probability of data loss

Tags: probability, permutations

There are 300 files, each of which has 3 copies. Evenly and (by some mechanism)randomly distribute all the 900 files into 10 hard drives such that no drive will contain both a file and its copy. Now 3 hard drives are broken. How much is the probability that there is at least one file lost?

by some brute-force method I got the answer:

$N=\sum _{n=1}^{90}(-1)^{n+1}{{n}\choose{300}}{{3n}\choose{270}}(3n)!(900-3n)! $

$A=900!$

$P=\frac{N}{A}$

I don't know if this is correct, and anyway this result doesn't look so "tidy". Is there some better way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: 300 files, each of which has 2 copies... where does the number 900 come from?

Comment: To answer my own question above: the meaning seems to be that for each file, there is an "original", and then two *additional* copies. I'd have stated this as "each file as 3 copies", but both interpretations are valid I guess.

Comment: How do you acchieve that even distribution? For each file randomly and independantly select three different disks? Or use a systematic distribution, e.g. file $k$ appears on disks $k, k+1, k+2\mod 10$? In the first case, Jon Schneider's answer applies, in the second the probability of data loss is $\frac{10}{10\choose 3}=\frac1{24}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: In your second case, the probability of data loss is actually $1 - \frac{10}{\binom{10}{3}} = \frac{11}{12} \approx 0.91666\dots$. This is (unsurprisingly) close to the other answer.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR that's actually why I mentioned both "2 copies" and "900 files"..I guess there might be confusion

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen good point, the strategy I had in mind(but failed to mention) was that I take a hash(MD5 for instance) of the file and map the hash to the 10 drives. When collision happens, just re-hash repeatedly. If we accept that the MD5 of a string is evenly-distributed in the set of all possible results, this strategy shall be good enough.

Comment: @AlexSu: Your strategy seems to actually correspond to Jon Schneider's answer (the three copies of each file get mapped to any 3 of the 10 files with equal probability, independently), and therefore there might not be exactly 90 at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the set of all $\binom{10}{3} = 120$ triples (size-$3$ subsets) of the $10$ drives by $T$, or to be explicit, 
$$
%    import itertools
%    T = itertools.combinations(range(1, 11), 3)
%    print '\{', ','.join('\{ %d, %d, %d \}' % t for t in T), '\}'
T = \{ \{ 1, 2, 3 \},\{ 1, 2, 4 \},\{ 1, 2, 5 \},\{ 1, 2, 6 \},\{ 1, 2, 7 \},\{ 1, 2, 8 \},\{ 1, 2, 9 \},\{ 1, 2, 10 \},\{ 1, 3, 4 \},\{ 1, 3, 5 \},\{ 1, 3, 6 \},\{ 1, 3, 7 \},\{ 1, 3, 8 \},\{ 1, 3, 9 \},\{ 1, 3, 10 \},\{ 1, 4, 5 \},\{ 1, 4, 6 \},\{ 1, 4, 7 \},\{ 1, 4, 8 \},\{ 1, 4, 9 \},\{ 1, 4, 10 \},\{ 1, 5, 6 \},\{ 1, 5, 7 \},\{ 1, 5, 8 \},\{ 1, 5, 9 \},\{ 1, 5, 10 \},\{ 1, 6, 7 \},\{ 1, 6, 8 \},\{ 1, 6, 9 \},\{ 1, 6, 10 \},\{ 1, 7, 8 \},\{ 1, 7, 9 \},\{ 1, 7, 10 \},\{ 1, 8, 9 \},\{ 1, 8, 10 \},\{ 1, 9, 10 \},\{ 2, 3, 4 \},\{ 2, 3, 5 \},\{ 2, 3, 6 \},\{ 2, 3, 7 \},\{ 2, 3, 8 \},\{ 2, 3, 9 \},\{ 2, 3, 10 \},\{ 2, 4, 5 \},\{ 2, 4, 6 \},\{ 2, 4, 7 \},\{ 2, 4, 8 \},\{ 2, 4, 9 \},\{ 2, 4, 10 \},\{ 2, 5, 6 \},\{ 2, 5, 7 \},\{ 2, 5, 8 \},\{ 2, 5, 9 \},\{ 2, 5, 10 \},\{ 2, 6, 7 \},\{ 2, 6, 8 \},\{ 2, 6, 9 \},\{ 2, 6, 10 \},\{ 2, 7, 8 \},\{ 2, 7, 9 \},\{ 2, 7, 10 \},\{ 2, 8, 9 \},\{ 2, 8, 10 \},\{ 2, 9, 10 \},\{ 3, 4, 5 \},\{ 3, 4, 6 \},\{ 3, 4, 7 \},\{ 3, 4, 8 \},\{ 3, 4, 9 \},\{ 3, 4, 10 \},\{ 3, 5, 6 \},\{ 3, 5, 7 \},\{ 3, 5, 8 \},\{ 3, 5, 9 \},\{ 3, 5, 10 \},\{ 3, 6, 7 \},\{ 3, 6, 8 \},\{ 3, 6, 9 \},\{ 3, 6, 10 \},\{ 3, 7, 8 \},\{ 3, 7, 9 \},\{ 3, 7, 10 \},\{ 3, 8, 9 \},\{ 3, 8, 10 \},\{ 3, 9, 10 \},\{ 4, 5, 6 \},\{ 4, 5, 7 \},\{ 4, 5, 8 \},\{ 4, 5, 9 \},\{ 4, 5, 10 \},\{ 4, 6, 7 \},\{ 4, 6, 8 \},\{ 4, 6, 9 \},\{ 4, 6, 10 \},\{ 4, 7, 8 \},\{ 4, 7, 9 \},\{ 4, 7, 10 \},\{ 4, 8, 9 \},\{ 4, 8, 10 \},\{ 4, 9, 10 \},\{ 5, 6, 7 \},\{ 5, 6, 8 \},\{ 5, 6, 9 \},\{ 5, 6, 10 \},\{ 5, 7, 8 \},\{ 5, 7, 9 \},\{ 5, 7, 10 \},\{ 5, 8, 9 \},\{ 5, 8, 10 \},\{ 5, 9, 10 \},\{ 6, 7, 8 \},\{ 6, 7, 9 \},\{ 6, 7, 10 \},\{ 6, 8, 9 \},\{ 6, 8, 10 \},\{ 6, 9, 10 \},\{ 7, 8, 9 \},\{ 7, 8, 10 \},\{ 7, 9, 10 \},\{ 8, 9, 10 \} \}
$$

There are two interpretations of what your "Evenly and (by some mechanism) randomly distribute all the 900 files into 10 hard drives such that no drive will contain both a file and its copy" means.

The first interpretation, which is both simpler to implement and simpler to analyze, is that for each of the $300$ triples of files, you choose some $3$ distinct drives of the $10$ uniformly at random (i.e., some element of $T$ uniformly at random), and assign these $3$ files to those $3$ drives. So the different (triples of) files are well and truly independent. After you are done assigning these, some $3$ drives fail, which correspond to some element of $T$. The probability that a particular file is lost is the probability that it was assigned to exactly those $3$ drives that failed (exactly that element of $T$ which failed), which is $\frac{1}{|T|} = \frac{1}{\binom{10}{3}} = \frac{1}{120}$. The probability that this file is safe is $1 - \frac{1}{120}$, and the probability that *all* files are safe is, as they are independent, $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{120} \right)^{300}$. The probability of data loss is therefore $1 - \left( 1 - \frac{1}{120} \right)^{300} \approx 0.91877...$. As an aside, note that this is well approximated by $1 - e^{-300/120} \approx 0.917915...$.

One thing to note is that under this interpretation, after the files are assigned to drives, you won't usually get *exactly* $90$ files in each drive. The probability of that happening is actually tiny. Out of the $|T|^{300} = 120^{300}$ equally probable assignments, the number of such assignments is the number of solutions to
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{t \in T} x_t &= 300 \\
\sum_{t \ni i} x_t &= 90 & \forall i = 1, 2, \dots 10 \\
x_t &\in \{0, 1, 2, \dots, 300\} &\forall t \in T \\
\end{align}
$$
which I would estimate is several orders of magnitude smaller. (Here $x_t$ is to be thought of as the number of file(type)s which are assigned to triple $t$.) (There is an alternative formulation with $3000$ variables that are $0$ or $1$.) (The probability of getting *around* $90$ files in each — say between $85$ and $95$ files — will be very large / very close to $1$.)

So the second interpretation is that you somehow — I don't know how you could implement this — assign files to drives such that the overall assignment of triples is one that satisfies the above system of equations, uniformly at random. Then, the probability of no data loss is the probability that for a particular triple (say the triple $\{1, 2, 3\}$, without loss of generality), no files are assigned to that triple. This is the number of solutions to the above system of equations with the additional constraint that $x_{\{1, 2, 3\}} = 0$, divided by the total number of solutions. The probability of data loss is then $1$ minus this probability. This seems extremely hard to calculate exactly, but it will be close to the other answer (will be around $0.92$).

Comment: thanks! I guess 0.92 is good enough

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the distribution is done uniformly at random (i.e., for each different file, we distribute its copies to the hard drives in the $\binom{10}{3} = 120$ different ways with equal probability), the probability that no file was lost is the probability that no file was stored on exactly those three hard drives. For each file, this probability is $\left(1 - \frac{1}{120}\right)$, so the probability that none of your 300 files are lost is

$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{120}\right)^{300}$$

and the probability that at least 1 file was lost is therefore

$$1 -\left(1 - \frac{1}{120}\right)^{300} \approx 0.919$$

Comment: This is approximately but not exactly correct, if the interpretation of the question is that each of the 10 hard drives will contain exactly 90 files (which seems to be the one the OP chose). If so, then the probability distributions are different (e.g. under your assumptions, there is a nonzero probability that some hard drive contains fewer or more than 90 files), so the 300 file(type)s are not strictly independent.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR got me right. I wanted there to be exactly 90 files in each drive. Thanks for answering!